# How to use loop and range function in python to visualize plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, density-plot, cdf

Im trying to understand How to use loop and range function in python( matplotlib package ) to visualize the **cdf** of the **Poisson** distribution in a **single density plot**??

= 3,4,5,6,7

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12,6)

for l in range(3,8,1):
   seq = np.arrange(0,20)
```

How can i build the rest of the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import numpy as np
You define the range of values to calculate the cdf outside the loop, and for every iteration, you have the values as x, and the cdf as y:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import poisson

Seq = np.arange(0,20)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12,6)

for l in range(3,8,1):
    plt.plot(Seq,poisson.cdf(Seq,l),label=l)
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
```

[image]